# Reading Files in Android

Tags: java, android, file, path

So the problem is that I can't read a file in Android.

The code is

```
Quotenprognose quoten = new Quotenprognose2013(new Beliebtheiten(new AsciiQuelle(new File("lotto_2011_2013.txt"))), 2011);
```

and the error is a simple NullPointerException.
The whole thing is working as a normal Java Application, but not as app.
Do I format the path wrong?
Just ignore my own classes, im sure the error is in the

```
new File("lotto_2011_2013.txt")
```

part.

Thanks for your advices!

Comment: You should include the stack trace of such failures in your question.  However, your comment that it works as a normal Java app but not on Android strongly suggests that you are trying to read a file which simply doesn't exist on your Android device.  While Android supports a file system, there isn't a very clear or direct way to get things there along with your app.  Typically the android-unique resources or assets mechanism are used instead (but these do not result in a java.io.File)

Comment: And for the record, no, `new File("lotto_2011_2013.txt")` is not by itself triggering your error - that does nothing on the filesystem, it merely creates a Java object which points to something which might *or might not* exist.  The problem would come about when you try to use it, if the target doesn't exist or you lack permission to it.

Comment: Yes you're right, the error is triggered at

    reader = new FileReader(dateiname);    

but anyways, it gets caught out by catching IOExceptions.

Comment: where is your file located?

Comment: Right in the main Project folder

Answer (score 0):

You should put the File in `getFilesDir()`. You do not have permission to read/write a File somewhere else.

```
new File(getFilesDir(), "lotto_2011_2013.txt")
```

Comment: That's *one of* the possible locations, yes.  Note also that the title says reading rather than writing, so it's likely that the data is packaged with the code - something that doesn't result in it landing in the location referenced by getFilesDir().

Comment: Where excatly does getFilesDir() lead? The File lies in the src folder

Comment: @DLIK - nothing in the source folder makes it onto the device as an actual filesystem file.  Look at the already mentioned android-unique assets or resources mechanisms.